# React Native: Text onPress not working on android

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following code:

```
<Text onPress={() => console.log('this won\'t print')}>Dumb text</Text>
```

According to React Native's documentation, this works great in both iOS and Android, however when I run it myself, it only works on iOS, while Android acts as if the `onPress` prop doesn't exist at all.

I know I can use `TouchableOpacity` (all other questions talk about this), but I just need confirmation on whether I am missing something or if this is how it always has been and the documentation is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems perfectly right and works for me... Try reloading or reinstalling the app 2-3 times.. It should work

This is what I tried and worked :

```
<Text style={{color:'white', fontSize : 50}} onPress={() => console.log("pressed")}>Hello</Text>
```

Comment: you are right, something had bugged out and I had to restart metro `react-native start`.